# $watch not updating subview

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-watch, angularjs-bindings

I have this directive that changes `$scope.mode` in the parent `$scope`:

```
angular.module('Selector', []).directive('mySelector', function() {
  var changeMode;
  changeMode = function(newmode) {
    var $scope;
    $scope = this;
    $scope.mode = newmode;
    $('.menu-open').attr('checked', false);
    return $scope.mode;
  };
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      mode: '=mode',
      id: '@id'
    },
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: './directives/modeSelector/Selector.tpl.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.changeZoneMode = changeMode;
      return scope.$watch((function() {
        return scope.mode;
      }), function(newMode) {
        return scope.mode = newMode;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

this directive is included into **main.html**, as well as a **ui-view** that loads a subview:

```
 <my-selector mode="current.Mode" id="{{current.ID}}"></my-selector>
 <!-- This binding works and updates properly -->
 {{current.Mode}}

 <!-- Subview container -->
 <div ui-view="sub"></div>
```

**subviewTemplate.html**:

```
<!-- This binding doesn't work! -->
{{current.Mode}}
```

the subview doesn't have a specific controller, and it uses the parent one, as from the settings in **app.js**:

```
.state('app.details', {
  name: 'appDetails',
  url: '/:zoneID',
  views: {
    'appContent': {
      templateUrl: 'main.html',
      controller: 'ctrl'
    }
  }
}).state('app.details.overview', {
  name: 'appDetailsOverview',
  url: '/details',
  views: {
    'appContent': {
      templateUrl: 'main.html',
      controller: 'ctrl'
    },
    'sub': {
      templateUrl: 'subviewTemplate.html',
      controller: 'ctrl'
    }
  }
});
```

and the controller used by both **main.html** and **subviewTemplate.html**:

```
angular.module('myController', ['services']).controller('ctrl', [
  '$scope', 'Data', function($scope, Data) {

    $scope.current = new Data;
    $scope.current.load();

    return $scope.$watch('current.Mode', (function(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log('Old value is: ' + oldValue);
      $scope.current.Mode = newValue;
      return console.log('new value is: ' + $scope.currentMode);
    }), true);
  }
]);
```

I don't understand why it works on **main.html**, updating properly, but not on **subviewTemplate.html**. `console.log` inside `$watch` prints the right value.

Any help? What Am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `return scope.mode = newMode;` there is no need of this, it's already done. You don't need to $watch for it since the two way binding with the `=` is already taking care of updating your scope. Furthermore why do you have the same ctrl for all your views ? They won't get the same instance of $scope, so what will work in one controller won't work on the other one. This is because each view will get his own $scope instance, unlike others things, $scope is not a singleton, only $rootScope is.

Comment: I though the subview, if no controller nor scope is created, uses the same parent scope (which I think it does, as I can properly use current inside the subviewTemplate.html). I removed both the return and the second $watch by the way, thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing a new instance of the ctrl controller. Remove that line and it'll use the parent controller which will be ctrl. For example:

```
'sub': {
    templateUrl: 'subviewTemplate.html'
}
```

Comment: you mean the controller?

Comment: Yeah. If you don't specify a controller, you can use the parent controller. It's usually best practice to have a different controller for each view (unless you don't need one, like in your case above). If you'd like to share data between the controllers, use a service.

Comment: Yeah yeah I got that, but in your answer you copied the template and not the controller. :)

Comment: Ah I see, oops! Glad I could help anyway :)